# write(*,'(A,g0.1,A,F10.2,A,F10.2)') "Original Price Tag Before Tax", & 1 Error: Fortran 2008: ‘G0’ in format at (1) in fortran

Tags: fortran, gfortran

i am a beginner and trying to learn fortran however i face the following issue , i'm an absolute beginner at this , i really find it challenging
i changed the g0, Iw and I but none work as specified as i saw in previous posts ,thhe same error keeps spawining again and again, b, the f10.2  also doesnt work

## **1. below is my code **

```
`program discount_chart
  implicit none

  ! Declare variables
  real :: original_price, discounted_price_cad, discounted_price_usd
  real :: max_price, min_price, discount_percent, cad_to_usd_rate
  integer :: i

  ! Prompt user for input
  write(*,*) "Enter the minimum price tag (in CAD, ending in .49 or .99):"
  read(*,*) min_price
  write(*,*) "Enter the maximum price tag (in CAD, ending in .49 or .99):"
  read(*,*) max_price
  write(*,*) "Enter the discount percentage (e.g. 20 for 20% off):"
  read(*,*) discount_percent
  write(*,*) "Enter the CAD to USD exchange rate:"
  read(*,*) cad_to_usd_rate

  ! Check validity of input
  do while (mod(min_price, 1.0) /= 0.49 .and. mod(min_price, 1.0) /= 0.99)
    write(*,*) "Minimum price tag must end in .49 or .99. Please enter again:"
    read(*,*) min_price
  end do

  do while (mod(max_price, 1.0) /= 0.49 .and. mod(max_price, 1.0) /= 0.99)
    write(*,*) "Maximum price tag must end in .49 or .99. Please enter again:"
    read(*,*) max_price
  end do

  do while (discount_percent <= 0 .or. discount_percent >= 100)
    write(*,*) "Discount percentage must be between 0 and 100. Please enter again:"
    read(*,*) discount_percent
  end do

  do while (cad_to_usd_rate <= 0)
    write(*,*) "CAD to USD exchange rate must be positive. Please enter again:"
    read(*,*) cad_to_usd_rate
  end do

  ! Print chart header
  write(*,'(A,Iw.6,A,F10.2,A,F10.2)') "Original Price Tag Before Tax", &
    " Discounted Price After Tax (CAD)", " Discounted Price After Tax (USD)"

  ! Compute and print discounted prices for each original price in range
  do i = 0, 100
    original_price = min_price + i * 0.01
    if (original_price > max_price) exit
    discounted_price_cad = original_price * (100 - discount_percent) / 100 * 1.13
    discounted_price_usd = discounted_price_cad / cad_to_usd_rate
    write(*,'(F12.8, F12.8, F12.8)') original_price, discounted_price_cad, discounted_price_usd
  end do

end program discount_chart`
```

## the error is below

```
main.f95:41:15:

   write(*,'(A,Iw.6,A,F10.2,A,F10.2)') "Original Price Tag Before Tax", &

               1
Error: Nonnegative width required in format string at (1)
```

Comment: Do you need to do anything more than replace the `w` in `Iw.6` with a number, one greater than or equal to `6` in this case?  The presence of the `w` suggests you've copied a source which models the integer edit descriptor as `Iw.m` and explains that the `w` is the width of the field into which to write the integer.  It is, but in your code it needs to be replaced by an integer.

Comment: Oh, and while I'm commenting, the question title doesn't match the error you report at the end of your question.

Comment: Please show the full error output. There is a different error in the title and a different one in your question.

Comment: I know it isn't (either of) your declared errors, but it really is quite difficult/unreliable/dangerous to compare two floating-point numbers for equality (as in "mod(min_price, 1.0) /= 0.49"). 0.49 might actually get stored as something like 0.4899995 or 0.490001, neither of which is 0.49